# Bug in ant macrodef

Tags: ant

I have a bug in the following ant macrodef definition:

```
  <macrodef name="xxx" description="does xxx">
    <attribute name="attr1" default=""/>
    <sequential>
      <echo message="doing yyy"/>
      <echo message="@{attr1}" file="${builddir}/zzz.xml"/>
      <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
      <xmltask report="true" source="${builddir}/zzz.xml">
        <call path="spuds" target="process-spuds">
          <param name="spud-kicker" path="@count"/>
        </call>
      </xmltask>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>
```

When it tries to call the target of the call inside the xmltask, i get a null pointer exception.

What am I doing wrong?

The file zzz.xml contains (supposedly) well formed xml.  It contains a top level tag called "spuds" with an attribute named count.  I want to invoke the spud-kicker ant target on the spuds tag and pass the value of the count attribute to that task.

Comment: what convinces you that the null pointer exception is thrown by ANT. Without a stacktrace to investigate it's more likely to be an issue with the 3rd party xmltask.